# Unable to set desired capabilities when calling Open Browser with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

I am unable to call the keyword Open Browser when specifying desired capabilities for IE. I'm not sure if its a syntax issue, but I have tried many ways have have searched google too with little help.

```
*** Variables ***
${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}  ignoreProtectedModeSettings:${True}
Open Browser  ${URL}  ${BROWSER TYPE} Non http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub  ${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}
```

Usually it throws the error 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch'

I have also tried

```
&{DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}  Create Dictionary  ignoreProtectedModeSettings=${True}
```

Or if there is a way to set the capabilities in java, then call Open Browser? Or even set the capabilities and launch the browser in java and have that instance of webdriver shared with robot in order to use the keywords?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try being a bit more clear and obvious about which argument is which to avoid potential issues, for example is 'Non' your alias in there?  The browser type variable is just passing in IE in this case?  I don't see an awful lot wrong with what you've done so hopefully just the argument problem.

Here's an example which can hopefully help:

```
 Open Browser    ${URL}   ${browser}         remote_url=${saucelabs-remote-url}         desired_capabilities=${saucelabs-DESIRED-CAP}

${saucelab-DESIRED-CAP}        name:${saucelab-test},platform:${saucelab-platform},saucelab-public:${saucelab-public},browserName:${browser},version:${saucelab-version}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am writing the below format, assuming that you are working with Robot Framework and you have permissions to edit Internet Options in IE browser

Please follow the below steps, which might solve most of your issues. Start from step 1 if your browser has proxy setting else you can start from 3rd step

1.I have enabled the proxy in IE.

2.Set environmental variable no_proxy to 127.0.0.1 before launching the browser(i.e..before starting the execution of testcase) Ex: Set Environmental Variable no_proxy 127.0.0.1

3.Set all the internet zones to same level(medium to high) expect restricted sites Open browser>Tools>Internet Options>Security Tab

4.Enable "Enable Protected mode" in all zones

Once you are done with above steps , now use "Open browser" to get start running scripts in IE